# Python Flask - Trying to run SQL query in a HTML file

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, flask

I'm trying to run a SQL query inside a header file. 
The SQL query is:

```
cur.execute("select count(*) from registered_users")
number_of_users = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

The header file is called "header.html"

```
app.route('/header'):
def head():
    cur.execute("select count(*) from registered_users")
    number_of_users = cur.fetchone()[0]
    return render_template('header.html', number_of_users=number_of_users)
```

The HTML code:

```
<div class="snowball">
Registered users: {{ "{:,}".format(number_of_users) }}
</div>
```

The index file:

```
app.route("/"):
def index():
    render_template('index.html')
```

I want to include the "header" file in all pages without having to make it render at "website.com/header". Is there a better way to do this on FLASK? What's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at flask templates: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/
Here is a very good guide https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates

Comment: you can include header file in all html pages. and then you can make template tag  to retrieve the header.html data

Comment: @rajvi what if you want to run code in the header html page such as SQL query? do you have to write an app.route in the application python file?

Comment: @xiholac761 you can make a template tag then when ever header.html called it automatically run sql query which is written inside the template tag.